# Marionette Show new element after increment

Tags: marionette

I am attempting to have a view where after every fetch of 20 different products from my backend (`.fetch()`), the DOM will display a product ad. The problem I am running into is that every time the collection fires the `add` event, the CompositeView is re-rendered.

How can I add Children Views to a CompositeView without re-rendering the whole parent?

```
define(["marionette", "lodash", "text!fonts/products/template.html",
'fonts/products/item-view', 'fonts/products/model', 'eventer'],
function(Marionette, _, templateHTML, ProductItemView, ProductsModel, eventer) {
    'use strict';

    var ProductsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        template: _.template(templateHTML),

        childView: ProductItemView,

        childViewContainer: '.items',

        productsLimit: 150,

        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(eventer, 'sort:products', this.sortCollection, this);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset sort add', this.render, this);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.setupSync, this);
        },

        sortCollection: function(field) {
            this.collection.sortByKey(field);
        },

        setupSync: function() {
            this.setupWindowScrollListener();
            this.render();
        },

        productsEnd: function() {
            eventer.trigger('products:end');
        },

        setupWindowScrollListener: function() {
            var $window = $(window),
                $document = $(document),
                that = this,
                collectionSize = that.collection.length;

            if(collectionSize <= that.productsLimit) {
                $window.on('scroll', _.throttle(function() {
                    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
                        wHeight = $window.height(),
                        dHeight = $document.height(),
                        margin = 200;

                    if(scrollTop + wHeight > dHeight - margin) {
                        eventer.trigger('fetch:more:products');
                        $window.off('scroll');
                    }
                }, 500));
            } else {
                that.productsEnd();
            }
        },
    });

    return ProductsView;
});
```

**Generate Ad Code**
Here is the code I am using to try to generate ads
https://gist.github.com/dennismonsewicz/aecf9bd0befe63e96ee6

Comment: Do you have a CompositeView filter in the view?

Comment: Are you invoking sort after you add a child?

Comment: @seebiscuit - I have updated my question with my CompositeView

Comment: @seebiscuit - Was wrangling with it this morning. I removed my call to re-render the view after a `sync` or `add` or `sort`. Just not sure how to insert an ad after every 20 items are fetched (the API is set to pull back 20 at a time)

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Your CompositeView is listening for `add` events on your `collection`. When a fetch brings in new models, the CompositeView will render these new children and insert them in their sort order (defined by the `collection`'s `comparator`). Try it.

Comment: @seebiscuit - Yes, that works. I'm struggling with the Ad portion of this app. Not sure how to insert one into the DOM after every 20 products are fetched (and keep the ad there during sorting).

Comment: Look at the last bullet on my answer: pass `{ reorderOnSort: true }` to your `CompositeView` on instantiation.

Comment: @seebiscuit - I added a gist to my question with the AdGeneration portion (the reorderOnSort option is working by the way). I made a comment or two on some issues I'm now getting

Comment: Looks good. Why don't you accept my answer and put this up on a second question. Let me know and I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @seebiscuit - new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347648/marionette-compositeview-children-findbyindex-not-working-as-expected-after-coll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's causing your parent view to re-render, is that you're calling a `render` on a collection add event :)

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset sort add', this.render, this);
```

Unless you really want to re-render that parent CompositeView you don't need this listener **at all** because Marionette handles:

- collection#add: [_onCollectionAdd](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/collection-view.js#L101) will render and place new childviews in the *default* (based on a comparator, if none then id) sort order
- [collection#reset](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/collection-view.js#L92): Marionette already has a listener on your CompositeView that will call `this.render` for you if your collection is `reset`
- [collection#sort](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/collection-view.js#L94): If you provide your view `{ sort: true }` as an option to your CompositeView, it will handle `'sort'` events on your collection. The default is to sort the children views and then call `render` on the CompositeView. If you *don't* want your CompositeView to be re-rendered, pass `{ reorderOnSort: true }` and the children view will be efficiently reordered without re-rendering anything (parent nor children), simply moving the children DOM elements in the sort order dictated by the `collection.comparator`.