# Marionette CompositeView children.findByIndex not working as expected after collection sync

Tags: marionette

I have the following code that happens *after* a collection sync:

```
    adGeneration: function() {
        var child = this.children.findByIndex(this.children.length - 1);
        console.log(child.model.toJSON());
        eventer.trigger('generate:new:ad', child);
    },
```

The problem I am running into, is that, after the first sync, the `child` element is a blank model:

First Time:

`Object {id: "5-vp39kv3uiigxecdi", size: 26, price: "9.84", face: "( ⚆ _ ⚆ )"}`

Every time after:

`Object {length: 40, models: Array[41], _byId: Object, _listeningTo: Object, _listenId: "l14"…}`

ProductsCollection

```
define(["backbone", "lodash", "fonts/products/model", "eventer"],
function(Backbone, _, ProductModel, eventer) {
    'use strict';

    var ProductsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ProductModel,

        sort_key: 'price',

        url: '/api/products',

        offset: 0,

        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(eventer, 'fetch:more:products', this.loadMore, this);
        },

        comparator: function(item) {
            return item.get(this.sort_key);
        },

        sortByKey: function(field) {
            this.sort_key = field;
            this.sort();
        },

        parse: function(data) {
            return _.chain(data)
                    .filter(function(item) {
                        if(item.id) {
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    .map(function(item){
                        item.price = this.formatCurrency(item.price);

                        return item;
                    }.bind(this))
                    .value();
        },

        formatCurrency: function(total) {
            return (total/100).toFixed(2);
        },

        loadMore: function() {
            this.offset += 1;
            this.fetch({
                data: {
                    limit: 20,
                    skip: this.offset
                },
                remove: false,
                success: function(collection) {
                    this.add(collection);
                }.bind(this)
            });
        }
    });

    return ProductsCollection;

});
```

LayoutView that contains the View for the productions collection. The collection is fetched onShow of the layoutview

```
define(["marionette", "lodash", "text!fonts/template.html",
"fonts/controls/view", "fonts/products/view", "fonts/products/collection", "eventer"],
function(Marionette, _, templateHTML, ControlsView, ProductsView,
    ProductsCollection, eventer) {
    'use strict';

    var FontsView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({

        regions: {
            controls: '#controls',
            products: '#products-list'
        },

        template: _.template(templateHTML),

        initialize: function() {
            this._controlsView = new ControlsView();
            this._productsView = new ProductsView({
                collection: new ProductsCollection({
                    reorderOnSort: false,
                    sort: false
                })
            });

            this.listenTo(this._productsView.collection, 'sync', this.loading, this);
            this.listenTo(eventer, 'fetch:more:products', this.loading, this);
            this.listenTo(eventer, 'products:end', this.productsEnd, this);
        },

        onRender: function() {
            this.getRegion('controls').show(this._controlsView);
            this.getRegion('products').show(this._productsView);
            this.loading();
        },

        onShow: function() {
            this._productsView.collection.fetch({
                data: {
                    limit: 20
                }
            })
        },

        productsEnd: function() {
            this.loading();
            this.$el.find('#loading').html("~ end of catalogue ~")
        },

        loading: function() {
            var toggle = this.$el.find('#loading').is(':hidden');
            this.$el.find('#loading').toggle(toggle);
        }
    });

    return FontsView;

});
```

AdsView:

```
define(["marionette", "lodash", "text!ads/template.html", "eventer"],
function(Marionette, _, templateHTML, eventer) {
    'use strict';

    var AdsView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: _.template(templateHTML),

        ui: {
            ad: '.ad'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(eventer, 'generate:new:ad', this.generateNewAd, this);
        },

        onShow: function() {
            // Set add image onShow
            this.ui.ad.prop('src', '/ad/' + this.randomNumber());
        },

        generateNewAd: function(childView) {
            var newAd = this.ui.ad.clone(),
                element = childView.$el,
                elementId = childView.model.get("id");

            newAd.prop('src', '/ad/' + this.randomNumber());

            $("#" + elementId).after(newAd);
        },

        randomNumber: function() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        },

        setUpAd: function() {
            this.ui.ad.prop('src', '/ad/' + this.randomNumber());
        }
    });

    return AdsView;
});
```

Comment: Could you post 1. Where the fetch is being called, 2. the `collection` definition, please?

Comment: This may sound weird (and probably won't be the fix) but can you try replacing `this.children.findByIndex(this.children.length - 1)` with `this.children.last()`. There's an issue with `findByIndex()` ( see [babysitter#49](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter/issues/49))

Comment: @seebiscuit - updated question with code. I tried the `this.children.last()` but still got the same thing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `ProductsCollection.loadMore` method. There, in the `success` callback to your `fetch` you do,

```
function(collection) { this.add(collection); }
```

What's happening behind the scenes is that before your `success` callback is invoked, Backbone will first run `Collection.set()` on your data. By default, inside `set` your data will be parsed into a array of models returned by `ProductsCollection.parse` and if any new models are found they will be `add`'ed to your existing collection (note that unless you pass `{ remove: false }` to your `fetch` options, models in your collection which are *not* in your last fetch will be removed. See [`Collection.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set))

So, what happens when you do the `fetch` in `loadMore`, which is called *after* the first `fetch`, Backbone will first `add` all the models from the server (that are returned from `ProductsCollection.parse`) and then invoke the `success` callback of your `fetch`, which, essentially does one last `add`. And what it's `add`'ing is the `ProductsCollection` instance. Not `collection.models`, an array of models, rather a Backbone object that has a property `models` that holds a raw array of models. Hence, the strange output:

```
Object {length: 40, models: Array[41], _byId: Object, _listeningTo: Object, 
_listenId: "l14"…}
```

Simply remove that `success` callback (which is unnecessary) and the last child view of your `ProductsView` should be the view rendered from the last model returned.

Comment: Wow, thank you!! That seemed to fix the "strange output" problem. The problem I am facing now is just that the new ad is being dropped in after the last child is added (not after each fetch; supposed to drop a new ad in after every fetch, or after every 20 records are fetched). I updated my code where I add in the ad to the DOM

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure I understand the new issue. Would you mind accepting this answer and explaining the new issue in more detail in a new question? Specifically, show where the `adGeneration` method is called.

Comment: certainly! You've been a huge help! Thank you!!

Comment: here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383640/marionette-drop-in-new-itemview-after-every-fetch-not-working